# Gridview Using ObjectDataSource - not displaying info

Tags: c#, web-services, objectdatasource

I've been unsuccessfully trying to bind a gridview through a web service, but nothing's showing up. Is there something wrong with my web method?

Here are what I have in my App_Code folder: membershipService.cs, DataAccessService.cs, Post.cs
membershipService.cs:

```
    [WebMethod(Description = "Display all users' post")]
    public Post[] DisplayAllPosts()
    {
        List<Post> usersPosts = new List<Post>();
        DataSet ds;
        Post p;

        try
        {
            ds = DataAccessService.RunSimpleQuery("SELECT username, post, postDateTime FROM UserPosts ORDER BY postID DESC");

            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                p = new Post();
                p.username = dr["username"].ToString();
                p.post = dr["post"].ToString();
                p.postDateTime = dr["postDateTime"].ToString();
                usersPosts.Add(p);
            }        
            return usersPosts.ToArray();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

DataAccessService.cs:

```
public static DataSet RunSimpleQuery(string query)
{
    DataSet result = new DataSet();
    OleDb.OleDbConnection connection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
    OleDb.OleDbCommand command;
    OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter;

    try
    {
        //open database connection
        connection.Open();

        //create database command for query
        command = new OleDb.OleDbCommand();
        command.CommandText = query;
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        //create data adapter and use it to fill the data set using the command
        dataAdapter = new OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter();
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
        dataAdapter.Fill(result);
    }
    catch
    {
        result = null;
    }
    finally
    {
        //close connection
        connection.Close();
        connection.Dispose();
    }
    //return dataset
    return result;
}
```

Post.cs:

```
public class Post
{
    public string username;
    public string post;
    public string postDateTime;
}
```

I'll appreciate any help I can get. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried putting a breakpoint on the exception handler in DisplayAllPosts to see if an exception is being thrown there?

Unless all of your database columns are non-nullable, you could have a DbNull.Value in one of your columns that is throwing an exception.

Comment: I've got it now: there was something wrong with my query. Thank you for your help, competent_tech!